# ORA-00984 on an after update pl/sql trigger

Tags: plsql

I have been fighting with this trigger for a while now, im trying to send to the table "MOVIMIENTO" the old stock, the new one, the difference between them and what kind of operation it is, only problem it's that i get an ORA-00984 error on line 12 and a sql statement ignored on line 11, any ideas?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_MOVIMIENTO
AFTER UPDATE OF "STOCK" ON PRODUCTO
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE  
 v_tmov VARCHAR2(7);
 v_cant NUMBER(6);
BEGIN
  v_cant:=:OLD.STOCK-:NEW.STOCK;
  IF :OLD.STOCK>:NEW.STOCK THEN
     v_tmov:='SALIDA';
  ELSE 
     v_tmov:='ENTRADA';
  END IF;
  INSERT INTO MOVIMIENTO(N_MOV,TIPO_MOV,STOCK_NEW,STOCK_OLD,CANT_MOV)
  VALUES(s_NUMEROMOV.nextval,v_tmod,:NEW.STOCK,:OLD.STOCK,v_cant);
END; 
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `v_tmod` a column on the `MOVIMIENTO` table. Because there is no variable with that name. That would explain the error.

Edit: OK, looking at the comments, I think I know what is going on.

The variables in the declare section are `v_tmov` and `v_cant`.
But in your `INSERT` statement you have made a typo and used `v_tmod`.
Oracle sees this is not a known variable so assumes it must be a column name. So it then reports the ORA-00984 error, without even checking to see if its a valid column name. This is because you cannot use a column here.

So the real error is `v_tmod` is not a defined variable

Comment: No it's not, the variable `v_tmod` holds the value that will be inserted on the column `TIPO_MOV`, it has the same format as `TIPO_MOV` too.

Comment: @OmarAlfredoCantuariasSaleh Where `v_tmod` is declared in your trigger?

Comment: It's in the `DECLARE` section o.o

Comment: Nope, you've got a typo. `v_tmov` is in the declare section. I updated my answer with a full explaination

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much, i couldn't see de letter at the end that made the difference